# In Django, why do I need __unicode__?

Tags: python, django

I'm starting to learn Django and I'm starting out with the Django book.
I came across this concept and I have a hard time understanding the logic..

The book says 
"Django uses Unicode objects throughout the framework. Model objects are retrieved as Unicode objects, views interact with Unicode data, and templates are rendered as Unicode. Generally, you won’t have to worry about making sure your encodings are right; things should just work."

Then why do you need to do "def **unicode**()" to print in unicode? Shouldn't it just work with plain vanilla print()?

Comment: it does work without it, the method is just to tell it *what* to print.

Comment: FYI: In python 3 you need `__str__` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried just printing a model instance that doesn't have a `__unicode__` method? You don't get anything really useful. That's where `__unicode__` comes into play. You get to define how your model instances are displayed whenever you try to use them in a unicode context.

Try this experiment. Create a simple model. Now print it out:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

>>> obj = MyModel("foo")
>>> print obj
```

See what you get. Now add a `__unicode__()` method.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Run it again:

```
>>> obj = MyModel("foo")
>>> print obj
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode ? It explains why we needs **unicod** well. Because python 2.x is not using unicode basically, django needs to handle unicode.